# Maximum volume using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, volume, lagrange-multiplier

I need to determine the **maximum volume** of a **rectangular box** with these side conditions: its **surface has 2m²** and the **sum of all its edges = 8 m of length.**

How do I do that ?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have, but the answer is simply gigantic to post in here. My answer is: 2+ 2sqrt(5).

Comment: "*Gigantic*"... really?  That's an indication you're off the mark on such a straightforward question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** The volume of rectangular box is: $\space V=V(x,y,z) = x \space y \space z$.

Side conditions:

$2xy + 2xz + 2yz = 2 \iff \varphi (x,y,z) = xy + xz + yz - 1 =0$;

$x+y+z=8 \iff \psi (x, y, z) =   x+y+z -8 =0$.

Now compose the Lagrange function: $\Phi(x, y, z, \lambda, \mu) =V(x,y,z)+\lambda \varphi(x,y,z)+\mu \psi(x,y,z)$, the extreme value of $\space \Phi \space$ will be an extreme value also for $\space V$.